# Adding bullet points to multiple textareas with same Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, bulletedlist

I found the below code online to add bullet points to a textarea, and it works quite well for a single textarea.

Script

```
var CRLF = 10;
var BULLET = String.fromCharCode(45);

function Init() {
    var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
        [].forEach.call(textareas, function(element) {
            element.addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);
        });
}

function OnInput(event) {
    char = event.target.value.substr(-1).charCodeAt(0);
    nowLen = txt.value.length;

    if (nowLen > prevLen.value) {
        if (char == CRLF) txt.value = txt.value + BULLET + " ";
        if (nowLen == 1) txt.value = BULLET + " " + txt.value;
    }
    prevLen.value = nowLen;
}
```

HTML

```
<body onload="Init ();">
    <h4>Automatic bullets in a text box</h4>
    <textarea id="txt" oninput="OnInput(this, 'prevLen');" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="prevLen" value="0"/>
</body>
```

However, I can't figure out how to create a similar function such that I can use it on multiple textareas.

I would like something where I can pass through the id of the hidden input, so I can specify that way which input to add the bullet points to, but can't get a working solution.

Suggestions/solutions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of all textareas and add the event listener

```
var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
[].forEach.call(textareas, function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", OnInput, false);
});
```

You can use any valid CSS3 selector to get the desired textareas.

As per your edit:
You can group the elements together so you can access them as a group. Now you can use the input in any way you like.

```
<div class="some_wrapper">
   <textarea id="txt" oninput="OnInput(this, 'prevLen');" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" id="prevLen" value="0"/>
</div>

var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('some_wrapper');
[].forEach.call(wrappers, function(wrapper) {
   var textarea = wrapper.querySelector("textarea"),
       input = wrapper.querySelector("input");
   //process "input" to get the desired "id", "class",.....
   textarea.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        OnInput(e, input)
   }, false);
});
```

Comment: I have added the above suggestion to my code, but the issue is how do I pass through the id of the hidden element to this method. I can't seem to figure this out, as the function OnInput is written based on the id of the hidden input being 'prevLen', but I would need to be able to use this method on multiple hidden elements.

Comment: @JellyTots A basic, non-functional example in my edit

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my query/issue:

Script/app.js:

```
var CRLF   = 10;
var BULLET = String.fromCharCode(45);

function Init() {

var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('panel-body');
    [].forEach.call(wrappers, function(wrapper) {
       var textarea = wrapper.querySelector("textarea"),
       input = wrapper.querySelector("input");
       textarea.addEventListener("input", OnInput(), false);
    });
}

function OnInput(ta,inp) {
    char = ta.value.substr(-1).charCodeAt(0);
    nowLen = ta.value.length;

    if (nowLen > inp.value) {
        if (char == CRLF) ta.value = ta.value + BULLET + " ";
        if (nowLen == 1) ta.value = BULLET + " " + ta.value;
    }
    inp.value = nowLen;
}
```

HTML

```
<body onload="Init ();">
<div class="panel-body">
<h4>Automatic bullets in a text box</h4>
<textarea id="ta1" oninput="OnInput(ta1, pv1);" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="pv1" value="0"/>

    <h4>Automatic bullets in a text box</h4>
    <textarea id="ta2" oninput="OnInput(ta2,pv2);" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="pv2" value="0"/>
</div>
</body>
```

The above solution solves the issue of adding bullets to multiple textareas.